# static_assert with partial template specialization

Tags: c++11, template-specialization, static-assert

```
template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct S { /* static_assert(0, "type unsupported"); */ };
template<typename T>
struct S<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type> {
    void foo() {}
};
...
S<int> i;
i.foo();
S<double> d;
// d.foo();
```

I would be expecting that the "master template" would never be instantiated for the case of `int`, but if I uncomment the `static_assert`, the `S<int>` instantiation will fail. Even a lone `typedef S<int> Si;` would fail to compile. (GCC 4.9.2 Cygwin)

What I aimed to achieve is not for `S<double>` to fail at the `foo()` call, but at the instantiation of the template itself, and that with a meaningful error message. I'm aware I can do something like `typename T::nonexistent_type t;` in the master template which will prevent the template for compiling, but that'd be inferior to a `static_assert` message. (Note: putting the `static_assert` within a function definition in the master template still fails compilation for `S<int>`)

Why does the `static_assert` fail even though that template is not instantiated? Is this mandated (or perhaps "unspecified") by the standard? Is there a way to fail with a `static_assert` the way I wish to?

Comment: see [Why does the `static_assert` always get invoked?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27738971/3953764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression in the `static_assert` must be dependent on a template parameter if you wish it to be instantiation-time only. This is guaranteed by Standard- the implementation may (but has no obligation to) check `static_assertion`s in templates that are not dependent on any template parameter.

Your code is a strange roundabout way of doing something like

```
template<typename T> struct S {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "type unsupported");
    void foo() {}
};
```

This clearly communicates to the compiler the dependency between the expression and the template parameter, and is far clearer and easier to read as well. I actually couldn't quite figure out if you wanted compilation to fail for integral types or for non-integral types.

Comment: I've reduced my original problem to the simplest one for demonstrating the problem. I need to discern various cases at compile time and fail for anything else, not matched by the many partial specializations. Thus the code above. I just realized that *any* dependency on the type suffices: `static_assert<std::is_integral<T>::value && 0, "type unsupported">` does what I want. (almost -- `typedef S<double> Sd` still compiles, but `Sd d` declaration fails, so it's rather okay)

Comment: @lrfy: Then the simplest thing to do is make an `is_valid` trait that combines the various partial specialization cases and use that as the conditional

Comment: @Puppy - I just had something similar myself. Your `is_valid` solution sometimes means writing two templates, both with all the specializations, instead of just one - and purely to get a better error message from the one you actually want. That could be a fair bit of clutter, and duplicating all the specialization cases means they could easily be inconsistent (though AFAICT that should never lead to run-time bugs). Writing the `static_assert` condition weirdly could be a better approach, and possibly it would be worthwhile having a `dependent_false<A>` template.