# Specialised template being compiled without instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I thought that template classes were only compiled if instantiated.

Consider, in a source file,

```
template<unsigned N>
class wumpus
{
    enum {value = N};
};

template<>
class wumpus<0>
{
    static_assert(false, "Why am I being compiled?");
};
```

The compiler "evaluates" the `static_assert` yet the (full) specialisation is not being instantiated anywhere.

I thought I'd only get an assertion if I declared `wumpus<0> w;` somewhere. What is going on?

Comment: [Why does the `static_assert` always get invoked?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27738971/3953764)